# Remove all roles after update user information

Tags: 7, theming

I override user edit form template, when i try to edit a user( this user assigned to two roles) so after submit the edit form the user not assigned to roles that he assigned before the editing.

When i tried to back to the original template the problem solved.

Please any advices?

```
<?php print render($form['form_id']); ?>
<?php print render($form['form_build_id']);?>
<?php print render($form['form_token']);?>
<div>
<div id="right">
<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['name']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['mail']); ?>
<?php $form['account']['pass']['#type'] = 'password';?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['pass']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_notic']); ?>
</div>
<div id="left">
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_birthdate']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_army']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_manager']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_phone1']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_phone2']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_address']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_job']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_hopies']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_cardnum']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_lagneh']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_hazb']); ?>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_user_pic']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['actions']['submit']); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't really understand your question. Can you add screenshots?

Comment: sory, i will rewrite the question.

Comment: I'm trying to understand as well.  When a user edit's their own account, the roles they were previously in are removed and they should not be? Or, are you asking how you can remove them from the roles when they edit their account?  Can you post the .tpl file?

Comment: the roles they were previously in are removed and they should not be,this is what i mean

Comment: First thing I would do is replace all those `drupal_render()`'s with `render()`, remove the 3 `render()`'s at the top and then call `drupal_render_children($form)` at the bottom. That would be the best way to do this, and may fix your problem.

Comment: You might consider using display suite, https://drupal.org/project/ds and using User: "manage form" from the display suite admin screen. This should give you the layout flexibility you need.

Comment: @Chris Rockwell i tried it and no hope

Comment: Are you using any of the user or form hooks in a custom module?

Comment: no i don't use any custom module in my site